# Get current opened file version

Tags: c#

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(Program).Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "")).ProductVersion
```

That code, is a one-liner, but has quite a lot of steps for it to return the File Version. Is there maybe a AppDomain way to get the File Version? (Or in general a shorter way)

(The code DOES work - I dont know why its being voted to close as "Broken Code")

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. Though the purpose is simple, it seems real and legit. I reopened now.

Comment: Looks more like a Stackoverflow question to me (and a duplicate at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493715/how-to-get-current-the-product-version-in-c among others). There's hardly anything to review here. Either way, you can use `Location` instead of `CodeBase.Replace(...)`, and apparently there's a way to obtain it from an assembly attribute.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet And as you can see, the SO link shows you how to do the above with even more steps, yet my code is still pretty long. Is there no AppDomain.Version or anything?

Comment: Judging by those answers, no, it doesn't get much simpler than this. Some frameworks or libraries may make this a little easier, but why bother? It's only a few steps. If you need to use this a lot then you can always make a utility function for it.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Just seems odd that the shortest way requires stuff like typeof and .Replace :l

Comment: Those SO answers use `Location` instead of `CodeBase.Replace(...)`, and `typeof(Program).Assembly` is one way of obtaining an assembly, but there are others (such as the static `Assembly.Get...Assembly` methods). It depends on which assembly you're looking for. EDIT: Many programs consist of multiple .dll's, so you can't just assume that there's a single assembly.

Answer (score 5):

This one line might be left as-is, it's short and simple enough to be fully understood at first sight (especially if outer method has a meaningful name). However it has the disadvantage to be hard to test because it is doing 3 things:

- Getting the assembly which is the entry point of your application.
- Resolving the full path of that assembly.
- Reading the version information of that assembly.

In an ideal world I'd probably want to test them in isolation but it might happen only when I will have a bug there, for sure I want to reuse this code elsewhere then I will introduce separate methods.

```
public static FileVersionInfo GetProductVersion()
    => FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(GetEntryAssemblyPath()).ProductVersion;

public static string GetEntryAssemblyPath()
    => GetAssemblyPath(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
```

I changed `typeof(Program).Assembly` to `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` because if I move it into a separate DLL then I won't have `Program`. Note, however, that they may differ (see later).

What I'd really change is the way you obtain the path. Hard-coding `file://` is tricky and unnecessary and you do not handle URL escapes. Moreover it will return an incorrect result if assembly has been loaded with `Load()`. It's easier to write a slightly more correct version:

```
public static string GetAssemblyPath(Assembly assembly)
     => Uri.UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(assembly.Location).Path);
```

Note that here I'm accessing `Assembly.Location` but it throws an exception for dynamically generated assembly and it's an empty string for assemblies loaded with `Load()`. A "better" version should then handle both cases:

```
public static string GetAssemblyPath(Assembly assembly)
{
    if (assembly.IsDynamic || assembly.Location == String.Empty)
        return ""

     return Uri.UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(assembly.Location).Path);
}
```

Little bit better but if we want to make `GetEntryAssemblyPath()` a reusable method we should do better because the entry assembly is not always defined (web applications come to my mind in this moment but I kind-of remember about other issues in hosted environments). The choice between `Assembly.CodeBase` and `Assembly.Location` isn't important here but in another context you should check for `Assembly.Location == String.Empty` also when using `Assembly.CodeBase`.

In your tests you can now verify `GetAssemblyPath()` in isolation and you may add separate tests for other functions when you will find an issue there (or when their code will be more complicate).

Last pedantic note: we're not checking if file effectively contains the required information and, usually, for assemblies it's also possible to read `ProductInformationalVersionAttribute` (which might be different).